# MySql update field value based on other field values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Im trying to create a query that will do the following:

Here is my table:

```
ID     total     paid     own       status
------------------------------------------------
1      100.00    100.00   100.00    0
```

and here is the query:

```
$total = 50;
UPDATE cart table SET paid = $total, status = CASE WHEN $total >= own THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

The idea is if total amount of field "total" is equal or greater than amount in field "own" update field "status" to 1, otherwize to 2.

Im not sure if I can do this with only one query, or I will need to update cart table, pull the results, perform calculations and than update again.

Comment: Doesn't it work? It seems fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE cart table SET paid = $total, status = If($total >= own, 1, 2)
Where ID = 1;
```

Comment: Im not sure if that is any difference, And probably dont need the `select` , just the `IF` will work

Comment: I think case is used in procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Its called conditional update query.

Your query will do what you mentioned. Except `table` keyword you defined it should not be there otherwise your query is fine:

```
UPDATE cart
    SET paid = $total,
        status = CASE WHEN $total >= own THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
WHERE
    --your condition
```

Comment: You realize OP is using `$total` to update the table?  instead of the field `total`? Otherwise looks like the error is the worng use of `table` keyword

Comment: Yes thanks for highlighting, but it won't effect on query.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack and SQL version dependent but what about:

```
UPDATE cart SET paid=$total, status=-($total>=own)+2;
```